# Javascript Button dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Please take a look at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/tt13/gkhrj/

What I want to achieve is, when I press down arrow to get dropdown menu, and when I press the button to do something else: something like http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#splitbutton

How to get this result? Any suggestions?

Comment: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns and scroll to split button dropdowns

Answer (score 1):

- extract span tag from button tag and add `class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"` to it
- remove `toggle="dropdown"` and class `dropdown-toggle` from button
- add some id to button, like *action-btn*
- create click event for button

new fiddle: [Changed](http://jsfiddle.net/farnabaz/hPFGA/1/)